# Deploying SQL Server 2019 BDC - In cluster deployment getting message "waiting for the control plane to become ready after _ Minutes"

Tags: kubectl, minikube, azure-aks, sql-server-2019, sql-bdc

I am trying to deploy SQL Server 2019 Big Data Cluster (BDC) using az login with my Azure portal Subscription. I ran below commands step by step

1. az group create --name aksbigdata --location westus
2. az ad sp create-for-rbac --skip-assignment --name http://westus_aksbigdata_sqlbigdata
3. az aks create --name sqlbigdata --resource-group aksbigdata --generate-ssh-keys --node-vm-size Standard_L8s --node-count 1 --service-principal AppId --client-secret SP_PW
4. az aks get-credentials --overwrite-existing --name sqlbigdata --resource-group aksbigdata --admin
5. SET AZDATA_USERNAME="admin"
6. SET AZDATA_PASSWORD="password"
7. azdata bdc config init --source aks-dev-test --target custom --force
8. azdata bdc config replace -c custom/bdc.json -j metadata.name=sqlbigdata
9. azdata bdc create -c custom --accept-eula yes
10. azdata login -n sqlbigdata
11. azdata bdc endpoint list -o table

Now I got struck in step 9 which is for creating BDC cluster . It started creating Cluster deployment then I got struck with below message -Is there any issue or it takes long time to create this cluster? Please need experts inputs to get out of this issue. I can provide the further details if needed.

```
Starting cluster deployment.
Waiting for cluster controller to start.
Waiting for cluster controller to start.
Waiting for cluster controller to start.
Cluster controller endpoint is available at 40.81.10.209:30080.
Waiting for control plane to be ready after 5 minutes.
Waiting for control plane to be ready after 10 minutes.
Waiting for control plane to be ready after 15 minutes.
```

Thanks,
Venkata

[image]

Comment: The cluster is bootstrapped via a pod called control- followed by a randomly generated string, if you issue a describe on this pod, what do you get ?.

Comment: correct please run some commands
az aks install-cli 
to get yourself a local kubectl client
then
kubectl get pods -A
This should show you the pods that are in a bad state, you should be able to look at the logs of those pods after that.

Comment: What output you get for the following command?
`azdata bdc endpoint list -o table`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to focus on troubleshooting on AKS/k8s side. Double pod status, describe the pods that are pending.
Take a look at the troubleshooting guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/cluster-troubleshooting-commands?view=sql-server-ver15